# How to select the database from multiple connection strings based on name using web APIs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

How to select the database from multiple connection strings based on name using web APIs and also how to use the same connection string for all the controllers rather than writing the database selection code in all the controllers. I'm writing the database selection code in all controls, I want to write it once and reuse it in all controllers. Using these controllers to connect to the database in Xamarin forms

Code for selecting the database based on clientname selection.

```
 if (clientname.SelectedItem.Text == "Client1")
        {
            connStr = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["client_db1"].ConnectionString);
        }
        else if (clientname.SelectedItem.Text == "Client2")
        {
            connStr = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["client_db2"].ConnectionString);
        }
        else if (clientname.SelectedItem.Text == "Client3")
        {
            connStr = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["client_db3"].ConnectionString);
        }
```

This is code which i want to reuse in all controllers,

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, the web site can't know which conneciton to use.

So, you have to add one more paramter/value to the web methods.

Call it database. Say you can pass A, or B, or C

Then in your code:

MyConnection = GetContstr(DataBaseParmater)

So, DataBaseParmater could be A, or B or C.

Thus you GetConStr routine would do this:

```
Public Function GetConstrt(strDB As String) As String

    Dim strCon As String = ""

    Select Case strDB
        Case "A"
            strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WebEasy.My.MySettings.DatabaseA").ConnectionString
        Case "B"
            strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WebEasy.My.MySettings.DatabaseB").ConnectionString
        Case "C"
            strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WebEasy.My.MySettings.DatabaseC").ConnectionString
    End Select

    Return strCon

End Function
```

And I suppose you could use a conneciton "A" or "B" or "C" as defined in your application, and do this:

```
            strCon = 
ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings("WebEasy.My.MySettings.Database" &
DataBaseContext).ConnectionString
```

So you setup 3 or 5 database connections in your settings, and then append the A or B or C to that connection context that resolves to the actual database connection.

So, your client side web method calls will have to know and decide which connection you want to use. You certainly would not pass or send the connection string from the client side web method calls, but some kind of context such as database connection A or B or C etc seems like the way to go. I suppose you could setup a session() value at the start which determines the database choice, and again have something like the above that selects the given connection.

So adopt the concept of a database context here. use 1, 2, 3 or A, B or whatever.
Thus all code will use a function GetStrCon(databaseContext) to resolve and choose the correct connection string. I suppose you could even create a table with the connections, and thus have getConstr() function pull a row from that table, and get the connection string that way. So really only a few routines.

Critical however would be some kind of "context" value and the web callers would have to thus always pass that context for the server side code then to resolve what connection string to use. Hopefully you not use say dataset designer (or now the newer entity frame work, as that's going to be far more problematic).

Comment: I have updated the query and also added the code, please help